# String to Dask Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dask-dataframe

I have a string that looks like: 'header1;header2;header n;Row1value1;Row1value2;Row1value3;Row2value3;Row n value n'

In Pandas I can use `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(spearreq.text), delimiter=';')`

but I cannot parse `StringIO` object to dask. How can I convert such strings to dask dataframes.